# Flickr API : SSL is required

Tags: javascript, api, flickr

The call of the flickr API is suddenly failing: 
I have the following response :

```
jsonFlickrApi({"stat":"fail", "code":95, "message":"SSL is required"})
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?
Thanks in advance for your help

This is my block of code:
      jQuery.ajax({

```
     url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/",
     type: 'get',
     async: false,
     data: {
              'format': 'json',
              'user_id': 'XXXX',
              'api_key': 'XXXX',
              'lang': 'fr-fr',
              'method': 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
              'photoset_id' : photosetId
           },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonpCallback: 'jsonFlickrApi',
     success: function(data) {//code
     }
```

Comment: Try `https://api.flicker.com` not just `http://`?

Comment: Ur ultimate man @Rup ; codeGod

Answer (score 4):

According official flicker's blog, they change the way that api flicker communicate, they using ssl, so in your plugin you have to change all http links to https and test it.